# Multi-variable particle question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A particle is initially at rest at the origin $(0,0,0)$. At time $t=0$ it begins moving with velocity:
$$V(t)= (cos(t)-tsin(t),1,sin(t)+cos(t))$$

- find the time $t$ at which the particle leaves the sphere $S: x^2+y^2+z^2=3$
- find the point $P$ at which the particle leaves the sphere
- find the acute angle of intersection between the particle path $r$ and the sphere $S$.

I tried integrating the velocity and then substituted into the sphere and got time=$1.2247$. Then I used the position (integral of velocity) to get the point $(0.1452, 1.2247, 1.1521)$. I don't know how to find the angle.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use LaTeX for typing your question, it provides better readability and makes the question legible. You can see the guideline for typing for help.

Answer (score 0):

IF $t_0$ is the time when the particle intersects the sphere, then the vector $ \vec v(t_0)$ has the direction of the particle at this time.
If $ \vec p(t_0)$ is the vector that finds the point of intersection (i.e. that has as components the coordinates of this point), then the angle $\theta$ between these two vectors is given by:
$$
\cos \theta = \dfrac{\langle \vec v(t_0)|\vec p(t_0)\rangle}{\langle \vec p(t_0)|\vec p(t_0)\rangle}
$$
where $\langle\cdot | \cdot \rangle$ is the inner product.

So the angle you are searching is 
$$\theta = \arccos \left[\dfrac{\langle \vec v(t_0)|\vec p(t_0)\rangle}{\langle \vec p(t_0)|\vec p(t_0)\rangle} \right]
\qquad 0<\theta<\dfrac{\pi}{2}
$$